# Split Revenue for Fiscal Quarters that Straddle Calendar Quarters in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have sales data (revenue and units) by Customer, by Product (type, id, description), by "fiscal quarter id", where the fiscal quarters are unique to this company and are not regular (i.e., not the exact same number of days for each).

I want (I think?) to "split" each row into two effective observations/transactions to allocate the proper share of the units and revenue to the two regular calendar quarters that the fiscal quarter straddles.

I also have a table (df2) that maps each of the company's fiscal quarters to calendar start and end dates.

Tiny sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'fisc_q_id': ['2013Q1', '2013Q2'], 
                   'cust':['Faux Corp', 'Notaco'], 
                   'prod_id':['ABC-123', 'DEF-456'], 
                   'revenue':[100, 400]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fisc_q_id': ['2013Q1', '2013Q2'], 
                    'fq_start':['2012-07-29', '2012-10-28'], 
                    'fq_end':['2012-10-27', '2013-01-26']})
```

Desired output would be FOUR rows, each keeping the original "fiscal quarter ID", but would add a column with the appropriate calendar quarter and the allocated revenue for that quarter.

I have some ideas as to how this might work, but my solution -- if I could even get to one -- would surely be inelegant compared to what you guys can offer.

Comment: When you say split rows, what criteria do you want to use to split the rows or the quarters into two?

Comment: As you can see from the mapping of the fiscal quarters to their start and end dates, each fiscal quarter above is comprised of some days from one calendar quarter and some days from another. So I want to split each into the relevant calendar quarters, and allocate the revenue based the share of days in each calendar quarter. E.g., fiscal 2013Q1 has 64 days in calendar 2012Q3, and 27 days in calendar 2012Q4, so the observation would be split into two new records, 2012Q3, with revenue * (64/91), and 2012Q4, with revenue * (27/91). Does that make sense?

Comment: See my edits and let me know. Happy to answer any questions.

Comment: Was it of any help?

Comment: Very! Still working through and comparing to what I came up with and will report back. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IICU

```
  #Merge the datframes
df3=df1.merge(df2)
#Coerce dates into datetime
df3.fq_start = pd.to_datetime(df3.fq_start)
df3.fq_end = pd.to_datetime(df3.fq_end)#Calculate the Calender Quarter for strat and end
df3['fq_startquarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df3.fq_start, freq='Q')
df3['fq_endquarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df3.fq_end, freq='Q')
#Calculate the end date of the first quarter in the date range and hence the day difference on either side of the partition
df3['Qdate'] = df3['fq_start'].dt.to_period("Q").dt.end_time
df3['EndQdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Qdate'], format='%Y-%M-%d')
df3['days1']=(df3['EndQdate']-df3['fq_start']).dt.days+1
df3['days2']=(df3['fq_end']-df3['EndQdate']).dt.days
df3['dys0']=(df3['fq_end']-df3['fq_start']).dt.days
df3.drop(columns=['Qdate','EndQdate'], inplace=True)
#Melt the calculated quarters
df4=pd.melt(df3, id_vars=['fisc_q_id','cust','prod_id','revenue','fq_start','fq_end','days1','days2','dys0'], value_name='CalenderQuarter')
df4.sort_values(by='prod_id', inplace=True)
#Allocate groups to the quarteres to allow allocation of calculated days
df4['daysp']=df4.groupby('prod_id')['CalenderQuarter'].cumcount()+1
#Set conditions and choices and use np.where to conditionally calculate revenue prportions
conditions= (df4['daysp']==1, df4['daysp']==2)
choices=(df4['revenue']*(df4['days1']/df4['dys0']),df4['revenue']*(df4['days2']/df4['dys0']))
df4['revenuep']=np.select(conditions,choices)
#Drop columns not required
df4['revenuep']=np.select(conditions,choices).round(0)
```

[image]

Curly one. Certainly opportunity to method chain so that it is efficient and faster.

Comment: Sorry forgot that bit.